# How to see if a string has more numbers than other symbols in java

Tags: java, numbers

So for an assignment I have to make a programm that asks for a input of a string and then detects palindromes.

thing is, also numbers can be put in. When more than half of the input of the string is a number it needs to regard the string as a numeric string and disregard the other symbols.

So what i thought is to put the input string into an array then look for the numbers (ASCII# between 48 and 57) and count those. Afterwards compare the number of Numbers vs number of Letters and see which one has more.

however, i can't seem to programm the thing that it counts the numbers in a string. can someone help me, i have this already:

```
public class opgave41 {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("input  a string:");
    String reeks = sc.nextLine();
    char[] array1 = reeks.toCharArray();

    int numbers;
    int other;

    for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){

        if (int array1[i] < 57 || int array1[i] > 48) 
            numbers++;

        else
            other++;

    }
    System.out.prinln(numbers);
    System.out.prinln(other);
}
```

}

if i compile it I get this:

```
opgave41.java:38: '.class' expected
        if (int array1[i] < 57 || int array1[i] > 48) 
                            ^
```

opgave41.java:39: ')' expected
                numbers++;
                                         ^
2 errors

how can i get this to worK?

Comment: Just a side node: There are many typos in your code. Have you tried using Eclipse or some other Integrated Development Environment? These would tell you where many of the errors are and highlight them.

Comment: yes i realize it now, just starting with learning java and i use textmate. My teacher didn't like eclipse i tried it but it is too much finctionality. Can you recommend me a good editor, without to much other functionality besides writing text en giving good colors/indention etc. I don't like textmate too much because it doesn't really auto-add { or ( etc. p.s. i have MAC OSX

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the obvious syntactical errors, I got this code based on yours:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("input  a string:");
    String reeks = sc.nextLine();

    int numbers = 0;
    int other = 0;

    for (char c : reeks.toCharArray()) {
      if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
        numbers++;
      else
        other++;
    }

    System.out.println(numbers);
    System.out.println(other);
  }
```

I also replaced the magic numbers 48 and 57 with character literals, since that makes the intention clearer.

Answer (score 1):

No need for loops, checks etc, its much easier with a regex in place for numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("input  a string:");
        String reeks = sc.nextLine();
        String symbols = reeks.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");

        System.out.println("others  - " + symbols.length());
        System.out.println("numbers - " + (reeks.length() - symbols.length()));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking `array1.length` which is the length of the character array.  I don't think that's what you intend.  You want `array1[i]` instead to get the current character.  Also, I think you have this backwards:

```
if (int array1.length < 57 || int array1.length > 48)
```

Assuming you fix this to use `array1[i]`, it will still be checking that the current character is **not** a number.  But then you proceed to increment the `numbers` counter.  Furthermoer, you may also consider using the `Character.isDigit()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is ok*, you just need to use the elements of the `char` array instead of the array length. So just replace

```
  if (int array1.length < 57 || int array1.length > 48)
```

with

```
  if (array1[i] <= '9' && array1[i] >= '0')
```

(note the `&&` since you want *both* conditions to be true. If you use `||` it will mean *less that 9* OR *more than 0* which is true for any `char`)

* *besides some syntactic errors*