# How can I extract the numbers from a string only using charAt(), length() and/or toCharArray() in Java

Tags: java

I have to do this for an assignment in my java class. I have been searching for a while now, but only find solutions with regex etc.

For my assignment however I may only use charAt(), length() and/or toCharArray(). I need to get from a string like gu578si300 for example just the numbers so it will become: 578300.

i know numbers are 48 - 57 in ASCII but i can't figure out how to do  this in java. You guys any ideas?

i was thinking about a for loop that checks whether the (int) char is between 48-57 en if so puts the value into a seperate array. Howeevr i dont know how to programm that last thing.

I now have this;

```
public static String filterGetallenreeks(String reeks){
    String temp = "";

    for (char c : reeks.toCharArray()) {
        if ((int) c > 47 && (int) c < 58)
            temp += c;
        }

    return temp;
```

however it is not working, it just outputs the same as goes in.

is it something in my mainm which looks like this. If i'm right the return temp; will return the temp string into the reeks string in the main right? why is my input still the same a sthe output?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Voer een zin, woord of cijferreeks in:");
    String reeks = sc.nextLine();

    if (isGetallenreeks(reeks)){
        System.out.println("is getallenreeks");
        filterGetallenreeks(reeks);
        System.out.println(reeks);
    }
```

Comment: Your idea is fine, and use a ArrayList<int> instead of an array, and I'm sure you can do the assignement on your own.

Comment: @sjaak: Should the output be a string?

Comment: You have already asked a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3850495/450398 and you got several answers that didn't rely on regular expressions.

Comment: @ Mark Byers: yes!
@Grodriguez: yes i know, the problem is i don't know how to make the new string without the numbers working.

Comment: @sjaak: Do you want to search for any numeric characters, including Chinese numbers, extended Arabic-Indic digits, etc? Or do you want to restrict to only digits between 0 and 9?

Comment: @sjaak: Have a look at the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework I will not be providing the complete solution, however, this is how you should go about it:

Do a for loop that iterates for the total amount of characters within the string (.length). Check if the character is a digit using the charAt and isDigit methods.

Comment: Note that IsDigit (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) is not the same as testing if the character is between '0' and '9'. Making this change could introduce (or fix, I guess) a subtle bug.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a reasonable approach, but I'd make a couple of changes from what you suggested:

- If you need to result as a string then use a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of an array.
- Use character literals like `'0'` and `'9'` instead of ASCII codes to make your code more readable.

**Update**

The specific problem with your code is this line:

```
temp = temp + (int)c;
```

This converts the character to its ASCII value and then converts that to a decimal string containing the ASCII value. That's not  what you want. Use this instead:

```
temp += c;
```

Comment: You and Claus are forgetting Java generics don't support primitive types.  `ArrayList<Character>`.

Comment: @MarkPeters: Thanks for your comment, but actually I changed my mind - now I prefer StringBuilder for this task. If he wants the result as a string then it is unnecessary to go via ArrayList first.

Comment: Yes i do need to have a string in the end. However i van only use the above three methods. And i think the purpose is to learn for loops etc. Can it be deno with those three?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a loop that checks a character in the string, and if it's a number, append it to another string:

```
//I haven't tested this, so you know.
String test = "gu578si300 ";
String numbers = "";
for(int i=0; i<test.length(); i++){
   if("0123456789".indexOf(test.charAt(i)) // if the character at position i is a number,
      numbers = numbers + test.charAt(i);  // Add it to the end of "numbers".
}
int final = Integer.parseInt(numbers);     // If you need to do something with those numbers,
                                           // Parse it.
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks for the input, i tried it but the compilergives this error (after modifieing it so it fits into my program). opgave4.java:98: ')' expected
     if("0123456789".indexOf(reeks.charAt(i)) // if the character at position i is a number,
                                                           ^
1 error

Comment: actually i update my problem, could you take a look again why it is not working. It now puts out the exact same i put in, not only the numbers.

Comment: Haha sorry I didn't respond in time. I know I didn't actually test that code, it was just some rough scratchwork.